# SQL Compact Error 80040E14 with multiple Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to execute this query on an SQL Compact DB with the SQL Lite Toolbox for Visual Studio 2015.

```
INSERT INTO [RadiatorRegistries] ([Brand], [Series], [Model], [Height], [Width], [Depth], [Whellbase], [Capacity], [Surface], [Q50], [Exp], [Typology], [Material], [Kc1], [Kc2], [KcR]) VALUES (N'Aermec', N'Climafon', N'33', 675, 1000, 140, 0, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 2001, CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'Termoconvettore', N'Alluminio', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT INTO [RadiatorRegistries] ([Brand], [Series], [Model], [Height], [Width], [Depth], [Whellbase], [Capacity], [Surface], [Q50], [Exp], [Typology], [Material], [Kc1], [Kc2], [KcR]) VALUES (N'Aermec', N'Climafon', N'41', 675, 1200, 140, 0, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 1810, CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'Termoconvettore', N'Alluminio', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
```

The returned error is:

```
[ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = INSERT ]
Error Code: 80040E14
```

If I remove the second line the INSERT is working fine, the problem is that I've to insert about 2500 rows and I can't manually do that. I've also already tried to add a semicolon at the end of each row.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try putting a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff already tried. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate each line with a GO:

```
INSERT INTO [RadiatorRegistries] ([Brand],
GO
INSERT INTO [RadiatorRegistries] ([Brand],
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `insert . . . select` with `union all`:

```
INSERT INTO [RadiatorRegistries]([Brand], [Series], [Model], [Height], [Width], [Depth], [Whellbase], [Capacity], [Surface], [Q50], [Exp], [Typology], [Material], [Kc1], [Kc2], [KcR]) 
    SELECT N'Aermec', N'Climafon', N'33', 675, 1000, 140, 0, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 2001, CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'Termoconvettore', N'Alluminio', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'Aermec', N'Climafon', N'41', 675, 1200, 140, 0, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 1810, CAST(1.30 AS Decimal(18, 2)), N'Termoconvettore', N'Alluminio', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2))
```